# What's the purpose of SizeHint in Iterator::unzip?

Tags: rust

From the Rust standard library [implementation of `unzip`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.8.0/src/libcore/iter.rs#L2052-L2080):

```
fn unzip<A, B, FromA, FromB>(self) -> (FromA, FromB) where
    FromA: Default + Extend<A>,
    FromB: Default + Extend<B>,
    Self: Sized + Iterator<Item=(A, B)>,
{
    struct SizeHint<A>(usize, Option<usize>, marker::PhantomData<A>);
    impl<A> Iterator for SizeHint<A> {
        type Item = A;

        fn next(&mut self) -> Option<A> { None }
        fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
            (self.0, self.1)
        }
    }

    let (lo, hi) = self.size_hint();
    let mut ts: FromA = Default::default();
    let mut us: FromB = Default::default();

    ts.extend(SizeHint(lo, hi, marker::PhantomData));
    us.extend(SizeHint(lo, hi, marker::PhantomData));

    for (t, u) in self {
        ts.extend(Some(t));
        us.extend(Some(u));
    }

    (ts, us)
}
```

These two lines:

```
ts.extend(SizeHint(lo, hi, marker::PhantomData));
us.extend(SizeHint(lo, hi, marker::PhantomData));
```

don't actually extend `ts` or `us` by anything, since the `next` method of `SizeHint` returns `None`. What's the purpose of doing so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a cool trick. By giving this size hint, it gives `ts` and `us` the chance to reserve the space for the `extend` calls in the loop. According to the [`documentation`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.size_hint)

> `size_hint()` is primarily intended to be used for optimizations such as reserving space for the elements of the iterator, but must not be trusted to e.g. omit bounds checks in unsafe code. An incorrect implementation of `size_hint()` should not lead to memory safety violations.

Note that the creation of `SizeHint` is necessary because the `extend` call in for loop is made with a `Some` value (`Optional` implements the `Iterator` trait), and the `size_hint` for a `Some` value is `(1, Some(1))`. That doesn't help with pre allocation.

But looking at the code for [`Vec`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.8.0/src/libcollections/vec.rs#L1377), this will have no effect (neither in [`HashMap`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.8.0/src/libstd/collections/hash/map.rs#L1641) and [`VecDeque`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.8.0/src/libcollections/vec_deque.rs#L2097)). Others `Extend` implementations may be different.

The execution of `ts.extend(SizeHint(lo, hi, marker::PhantomData));` does not trigger a `resize`, since `next` returns `None`. Maybe some one should write a patch.

```
impl<T> Vec<T> {
    fn extend_desugared<I: Iterator<Item = T>>(&mut self, mut iterator: I) {
        // This function should be the moral equivalent of:
        //
        //      for item in iterator {
        //          self.push(item);
        //      }
        while let Some(element) = iterator.next() {
            let len = self.len();
            if len == self.capacity() {
                let (lower, _) = iterator.size_hint();
                self.reserve(lower.saturating_add(1));
            }
            unsafe {
                ptr::write(self.get_unchecked_mut(len), element);
                // NB can't overflow since we would have had to alloc the address space
                self.set_len(len + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Will it help if I move the `let len = self.len(); if len == self.capacity() { let (lower, _) = iterator.size_hint();        self.reserve(lower.saturating_add(1));  }` part before the while loop?

Comment: In fact, I think we don't need to check `self.capacity()` at all, should just go ahead and reserve.

Comment: Adding a `reserve` before the loop is sufficient to trigger the `unzip` trick. Removing the `reserve` inside the loop may not be a good idea.  I think that this scheme helps with iterators that keeps updating the `size_hint` to be more accurate.

Comment: Sufficient only if you are unzipping into `Vec`s, right?

Comment: Right. Only sufficient if unzipping into `Vec`s.

Answer (score 5):

It's a dubious hack!

It implements an iterator with a fake (overestimated) size hint to encourage the produced collection to reserve the eventually appropriate capacity up front.

Cool trick but, it does so by implementing a size hint where the estimated lower bound is greater than the actual number of elements produced (0). If the lower bound is not known, the iterator should return a lower bound of 0. This implementation is arguably very buggy for this reason, and the collection's Extend impl may react with bugginess as a result (but of course not memory unsafety.)